# ROS publish Boolean Array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to publish a boolean array in a ROS msg. 
The boolean array is generated by the Open CV Canny Edge Detector. So there are just True or False values in the array. The array has the size of an image, in my case 1280x1024.

I'm trying to use the ByteMultiArray msg from the std_msgs. The following shows the code I got so far (just the important stuff for this problem):

```py
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import ByteMultiArray

NeedleBorder = rospy.Publisher('NeedleBorder', ByteMultiArray, queue_size=10)

frame_edges = cv2.Canny(frame_gray, threshold1, threshold2)
frame_edges_bool = frame_edges.astype(bool)

NeedleBorder.publish(frame_edges_bool)
```

If I run this code I get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VideoPublisher.py", line 73, in <module>
    NeedleBorder.publish(frame_edges_bool)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 816, in publish
    data = args_kwds_to_message(self.data_class, args, kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msg.py", line 122, in args_kwds_to_message
    return data_class(*args)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/std_msgs/msg/_ByteMultiArray.py", line 72, in __init__
    super(ByteMultiArray, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 276, in __init__
    raise TypeError("Invalid number of arguments, args should be %s"%str(self.__slots__)+" args are"+str(args))
TypeError: Invalid number of arguments, args should be ['layout', 'data'] args are(array([[False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       ..., 
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False]], dtype=bool),)
```

The ROS wiki doesn't help me in this case. Though I think this http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/ByteMultiArray.html and this http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/MultiArrayLayout.html somehow leads to the answer, but sadly not for me.

Thanks in advance for every help and hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest just publishing image messages, if that's what the data actually corresponds to. For that, there's already a helper library for converting between opencv2 types and ROS message types:

```py
import rospy
from cv_bridge import CvBridge
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image

image_pub = rospy.Publisher("image_topic_2",Image)

frame_edges = cv2.Canny(frame_gray, threshold1, threshold2)

image_pub.publish(self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(frame_edges, "mono8"))
```

For more details on cv_bridge, see this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython

If you *really* want to use `ByteMultiArray`, then you can do so, but you do need to create a  `MultiArrayLayout` which describes the dimensions of the data. Doing that is a bit onerous, though, and you won't be able to visualize the images with standard ROS tools.

Also, in the future, you're better off asking questions like this on http://answers.ros.org